# Do wave washers need to be on either end of bearings in double bearing induction motor

Tags: motors, bearings

I have a typical small electric induction motor given to me in pieces. 
It has two **wave washers** which I am told should sit between the bearing and the assembly.

I am not sure which bearing needs the wave washers.

1. Do I place on one wave washer before the front and rear bearings ?
2. Both wave washers on the rear bearing?
3. Both wave washers on the front bearing?

Please advise.

Comment: Update: After placing both wave washers at one side of the shaft I could hear the shaft grinding in the back plate. Definitely not what it is meant to do. Thanks for the feedback guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume one wave washer for each bearing - this allows pre-load to limit any play and expansion control as it get hot in normal operation.

Comment: This is not universal. I just took apart a 1990s 5HP motor which had 2 wave washers stacked together at one end only.

Comment: @StayOnTarget probably badly assembled by a cowboy in the past...

Comment: In my case the two bearings are different sizes... the two washers are the same. So perhaps 1 washer would have done it but the second couldn't fit at the other (larger) end.

Answer (score 2):

I intuitively agree with Solar Mike, there should be one washer per bearing. I wanted to find a source/reference, however:

This image appears to show wave washers in front of each bearing 
[image: motor cross section 1]

But this image doesn’t appear to show any wave washers at all:[image: motor cross section 2]

So the short answer is: probably 1 washer per bearing, but it will of course depend on the exact motor design. We’ll need more information from you if you want us to comment further.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,only one wave washer at each end located under the bearings to add pressure to keep them in place.

Comment: Did you have more to add to the answer?  It seems like there could be more detail that you could add.

Answer (score 0):

Wave washers allow axial expansion of shaft due to heat and keep preload, takes care of misalignment of shaft wrt to connecting load shaft, allows the vibration coming  to move the shaft slightly and thus reducing axial load on the bearing because of vibration and external load .

Hence they are to be provided on both sides